# i cant get my shot to travel directly to my cursor

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

I am making a 2d game with javascript and i can't get the shot to travel in a line directly to the cursor. I want it so when the shoot function is called th make the shot travel to the cursor and not alter the path when the cursor is moved after the shot is already out. Right now it is onnly going diagonal to the player

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onclick="shoot()">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
canvas {
    border:4px solid #000000;
    background-color: #26af2d;
}
</style>
<body onload="startGame()">
  <div name="buttonDiv">
    <button type="button" id="startRoundBtn" onclick= startWave();>dont mind this</button>
    </div>
    <p id="demo">
    </p>
  
  <script>
  let playerHealth = 100;
  let shot = false;
  let enemyOut = false;
  let waveActive = false;
  let enemyDmg = 25;
  let playerImmuneTime = 0;
//start
var player;
var TopEdge;
var BottomEdge;
var RightEdge;
var LeftEdge;
let Enemy;
var projectile;
function startGame() {
player = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
TopEdge = new component(10000, 200, "purple", 0, -200);
BottomEdge = new component(10000, 1, "purple", 0, 500);
RightEdge = new component(1000, 500, "purple", 1150, 0);
LeftEdge = new component(1000, 500, "purple", -1000, 0);
var x = document.getElementById("startRoundBtn");
myGameArea.start();
}
//game area
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1150;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,
        document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 10);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    },
    clear : function(){
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function(){
      clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
//coords
var pointerX = 0;
var pointerY = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    pointerX = event.pageX;
    pointerY = event.pageY;
}
setInterval(pointerCheck, 1);
function pointerCheck() {
  var cursorCoords = 'Cursor Location: '+pointerX+'X, '+pointerY+'Y    health: ' + playerHealth + '          imune time:' +playerImmuneTime
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cursorCoords;
}
//compenents
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
  ctx = myGameArea.context;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
//new pos
this.newPos = function() {
    this.X += this.speedX;
    this.Y += this.speedY;
    }
//crashing
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
    (mytop > otherbottom) ||
    (myright < otherleft) ||
    (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}
//updates
function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  if (playerHealth > 0) {
    player.newPos();
  player.update();
  }
  TopEdge.update();
  BottomEdge.update();
  RightEdge.update();
  LeftEdge.update();
  if (shot == true) {
    projectile.update();
    projectile.newPos();
    projectile.speedX = 0;
    projectile.speedY = 0;
  }
  if (enemyOut == true && playerHealth > 0) {
    if (Enemy.crashWith(player) && playerImmuneTime <= 0) {
      playerHealth = playerHealth -= enemyDmg;
      playerImmuneTime = 50;
    } if (playerImmuneTime >= 0) {
      playerImmuneTime -= 1;
    }
    Enemy.newPos();
    Enemy.update();
    Enemy.speedX = 0;
    Enemy.speedY = 0;
  }
  player.speedX = 0; 
  player.speedY = 0;
//movement
  if (myGameArea.keys[65] ) {player.speedX = -2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys[68] ) {player.speedX = 2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys[87] ) {player.speedY = -2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys[83] ) {player.speedY = 2.5; }

  if (myGameArea.keys[82]) {waveActive = true;}
  
  if (myGameArea.keys[75]) {waveActive = false;}

  if (enemyOut == true && player.x >= Enemy.x) {Enemy.speedX = 1; }
  if (enemyOut == true && player.x <= Enemy.x) {Enemy.speedX = -1; }
  if (enemyOut == true && player.y >= Enemy.y) {Enemy.speedY = 1; }
  if (enemyOut == true && player.y <= Enemy.y) {Enemy.speedY = -1; }
  
  if (waveActive == true && enemyOut == false) {
  createEnemy();
  }
  if (shot == true && pointerX > player.x) {projectile.speedX = 10};
  if (shot == true && pointerX < player.x) {projectile.speedX = -10};
  if (shot == true && pointerY > player.y) {projectile.speedY = 10};
  if (shot == true && pointerY < player.y) {projectile.speedY = -10};
  if (shot == true && enemyOut == true && projectile.crashWith(Enemy)) {
    shot = false;
    enemyOut = false;
    waveActive = false;
  }
//edges of game area
  if (player.crashWith(TopEdge) && myGameArea.keys[87]) {
        player.speedY = 0;
  }
    if (player.crashWith(RightEdge) && myGameArea.keys[68]) {
        player.speedX = 0;
  }
    if (player.crashWith(BottomEdge) && myGameArea.keys[83]) {
        player.speedY = 0;
  }
    if (player.crashWith(LeftEdge) && myGameArea.keys[65]) {
        player.speedX = 0;
  }
  player.x += player.speedX;
  player.y += player.speedY;
  Enemy.x += Enemy.speedX;
  Enemy.y += Enemy.speedY;
  projectile.x += projectile.speedX;
  projectile.y += projectile.speedY;
}
function createEnemy() {
  Enemy = new component(30, 30, "purple",
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 1100),
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
  enemyOut = true;
}

function shoot() {
  let midPlayerX = player.x + 12;
  let midPlayerY = player.y + 12;
  projectile = new component(5, 5, "white", midPlayerX, midPlayerY);
  shot = true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+trajectory+OR+%22collision+detection%22+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

you need to 'freeze' the `pointerX` and `pointerY` values between the shot being fired and reaching its destination (otherwise those values will change on mousemove).

You already have `shot=true` when the projectile is launched so it can be read in a conditional you add to your mousemove event listener. That will take care of freezing the pointers when the projectile is fired :

```
document.onmousemove = function (event) {
  if (!shot) {
    pointerX = event.pageX
    pointerY = event.pageY
  } // prevent updates to pointers when shot is fired;
}
```

but you will need to reactivate the listener by setting `shot` to `false` when the projectile colides with the stored `pointerX` and `pointerY` values.

Comment: this will help, thank you. however i don't know to actually move the shot to those coordinates

Comment: Your question suggests that the projectile is being fired and is moving (presumably following the mouse). If so, it is moving towards the pointers. Once they are frozen, it will move towards the frozen point. You then need to set `shot` to `false` when its position meets or overlaps the pointer coordinates. Lots of example of detecting collisions on youtube etc. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MyPLZSGS3s. It would help if you can post a functioning snippet here.

Comment: I have added a code sample above